# Gizmo controls disapear behind the gizmo (viewport question)

Tags: 3d-view, gizmo

I'm still new to blender so excuse my noob question;)
but I think it's super anoying that the handle of the gizmo disapears behind the gizmo itself when you look at it (semi) directly at it and I asume this is a option which I can disable. but I haven't found out how, so I need someone to tell me please:D

In the picture you see the X and Z axis handle, and I also want to see the Y axis from this perspective, instead of rotating my cam to be able to move it.
[image]

Comment: The Y-axis handle is there too but it's just a green dot which you can drag. There's no way of disabling that behaviour as far as I know, but most folks would use hotkeys (G Y in this case) to move the object or Middle-Mouse-Button drag to rotate the view..

Comment: hmm to me the Y handle is fading away once I get close to centre. the green block u see on the pic is a combination of the X & Z axis...

I really don't like reaching for my keyboard everytime im moving stuff..

Comment: Can't really help any further on that one. I very rarely use the gizmo, or even have it activated for that matter.